# What can I do about "a fire is raging"?

Tags: cities-in-motion

This message keeps popping up. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing you can or should do about it if it doesn't affect your transit lines.

I haven't played Cities in Motion in a while, but if memory serves, I haven't seen any effects from the fires that lasted long enough to require any action on my part.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. The red text with that message makes it seem like something needs to be done on my end!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, but you should be aware that when "a fire is raging", the fire engines will operate in the roads around the building on fire, blocking the circulation for a few seconds.